# Tensorflow, placement of shared variable definitions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a doubt about the definition of TensorFlow models. 
I am implementing a rather peculiar neural network model, where I need to access to the values of the output level for different inputs to compute the loss function...

So, I defined the layers of the neural network in a function like this:

```
def g(input_x,....):
###...Convolutional and Fully Connected Layers...###
# Last FC Layer
with tf.name_scope("output"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden_units, num_classes], stddev=0.05), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")
    scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(fc_2_output, W, b, name="output")
return scores
```

And then in my model I have something like this:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement=FLAGS.allow_soft_placement,
        log_device_placement=FLAGS.log_device_placement)
    sess = tf.Session(config=session_conf)
    with sess.as_default():
         ###definition of other variables, constants and placeholders###

         ###weird loss function with scores from different inputs###
         loss_function = tf.reduce_mean(alpha1 * weights_ll * tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=g(input1), labels=labels1) \
                        + cu1 * tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=g(input2), labels=g(input1) \
                        + cv1 * tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=g(input1), labels=labels2))) \
                        + ... + ...
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss_function, global_step=global_step)
           ##...training steps and such...##
```

The training is working, but without running it for too long I am getting strange results, and I wonder if the weights defined in the g functions are being trained or they are somewhat out of scope of the optimizer.

Unfortunately, I am still learning a lot about tensorflow and I have no TensorBoard results to show you right now.

I just need to know from someone with a bit more experience if it is legal to define a model like this, using a python function for outputs.

Thank you very much for reading this far

Comment: Hi, its good to define model as python functions. There is not accessing issue with that. If there is any problem, that might be because of loss function. Please show what type of strange results you're getting. Is loss reducing ?

Comment: Loss is reducing into big negative values in the order of -1e+15
but accuracy is not increasing, it's a binary classification problem and it averages to 0.5 (random guess)

Comment: Did you try with simple loss function (one set of inputs) ? Is accuracy changing in that case ?

Comment: Very slowly, but yes. But maybe this is due to the complexity of the model more than anything (convolutional nn). I guess I just have to wait and see.
In any case, this suggestion was very useful because it helped me rule out that there was something wrong with the loss function. 
We purposefully introduced a bias for an experimental semi-supervised learning procedure. But simplifying the loss function (reducing it to only the supervised part) shows that it stays in much more reasonable values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, in the loss function I used the scores (output values of network) for different inputs, and I compare them using the cross_entropy function.

```
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name=None)
```

This function computs the softmax of the logits, but naturally it doesn't compute them for the labels, so, in order to properly compare the scores of different inputs I need to wrap the "labels" with tf.nn.softmax() function, like this: (notice the last term)

```
loss_function = tf.reduce_sum(alpha1 * weights_ll tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=g(input1), labels=tf.nn.softmax(g(input))
```

In case you are curious why I need to do something like this, and you are interested in Deep Learning, I invite you to read this interesting paper on Neural Graph Machines: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.04818

Also, there is another big problem with this model, that I don't share variables, so in practice with this loss function it's like training multiple networks for each term of the loss_function.

Luckily, there is a tutorial in the TensorFlow website that addresses Sharing Variables: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variable_scope

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to initialize the variables with

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Other than that we can't really decide whether the model is feasible or not without understanding the model and the code.

Comment: Yes of course the variables are initializing otherwise I wouldn't have been able to train it at all. The entire code is online at https://github.com/gssci/neural-graph-network-sentiment-analysis/blob/training/neural_graph_machine.py

but the important part is really all there I think :)